# SQL Server, Full text search word breakers

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

In the sql server documentation for Full Text Search, and validated in production sadly, searching using english language the system will match exact phrases ignoring punctuation between words.

Books online says:

> Punctuation is ignored. Therefore, CONTAINS(testing, "computer
>   failure") matches a row with the value, "Where is my computer? Failure
>   to find it would be expensive."

Is there a word breaker for english that doesn't ignore punctuation so rows like their example would not be returned?

Answer (score 0):

That is the limitation of FTS or say good thing of FTS. FTS is used to fast search as well as this type of search where you don't know exact string.

If you want exact or ignoring this type of thing, you have to use Like search rather than FTS.